# How to set binary installed by package manager as default?

Tags: osx, package-management, binary

I installed a newer version of `tcpdump` via MacPorts and would like to make it the default binary.

```
$ which -a tcpdump
/usr/sbin/tcpdump
/opt/local/sbin/tcpdump
```

For now I set an `alias`, but that of course doesn't prevent `man` to show the older documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `OS X 10.8.5`, `bash 3.2.53(1)`, `MacPorts 2.3.4` you should actually do nothing.

I don't know though why it didn't work at first. `PATH`'s value might have somehow been stored and not updated (more on this below).

I tried

· `MANPATH` as suggested by *thrig*, but that didn't work. From `man`'s man page:`"It overrides the configuration file and the automatic search path"`.

· `export`ing the `PATH` from my (global) profile with the directories of the package manager first. That prefixed them thrice and suffixed them once and it did set the newer binaries/man pages as default, but I was curious about this new longer composition of `PATH` (the old value had all directories just once but in a different order, OS's defaults first, then package manager's).

For this topic check over at SU, [Where does $PATH get set in OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard).

It turns out `MacPorts` installer adds the directories in `~/.profile`.

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-10-10_at_20:55:20: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

I had this multiple times, so I proceeded to comment all, except the last one. That resulted in a clean `PATH`.

But how does `man` actually get the newer documentation?

From the `SEARCH PATH FOR MANUAL PAGES` section:

```
In  addition,  for  each  directory in the command search path (we'll call it a "command
directory") for which you do not have a MANPATH_MAP statement, man automatically looks for
a manual page directory "nearby" namely as a subdirectory in the command directory itself or
in the parent directory of the command directory.

You can disable the automatic "nearby" searches by including a NOAUTOPATH statement in
/private/etc/man.conf.
```

I corroborated this by temporarily enabling `NOAUTOPATH`.

Example

```
$ type tcpdump
tcpdump is /opt/local/sbin/tcpdump

$ ll -d /opt/local/man
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  9 Oct 10 20:55:20 2015 /opt/local/man -> share/man
```

For other package managers YMMV, but not much I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to adjust your `PATH` and `MANPATH` environment variables to list the MacPorts paths ahead of the vendor ones. For `bash`, try something like the following in your `.bashrc` (or possibly also `.bash_profile`) and then `exec bash` to reload the running shell:

```
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
```

Other handy commands might be to see what the current `MANPATH` is, and to find all the possible places MacPorts hides man pages (not all might be man page dirs, though, proper ones should have `man[0-9]` subdirs...):

```
echo $MANPATH
find /opt -type d -name man
```

`PATH` is a similar, basically:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

should be the simplest option, but again, test with `exec bash` and `echo $PATH`...

Beware, though, that Apple has a `/usr/libexec/path_helper` script that runs from global rc files (`grep -l path_helper /etc/* 2>/dev/null`). Your customizations must happen *after* this program alters `PATH` and `MANPATH`, as otherwise `path_helper` will reset things to what Apple sets by default. The `path_helper` output can be used as a starting point:

```
/usr/libexec/path_helper -s >> ~/.bashrc
```

And then edit those lines appended to include the paths you want in the order you want. (Do not use just `>` as that will *clobber* your `.bashrc` file, `>>` is append...)

Comment: `GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)` but I plan to install v4.